# GFCircleQuery doesn't return any result

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location, geofire

I use[Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) for iOS. I faced the following problem, I use Geofire to get the cards and users that are next to the current user. For cards, the result is correct, but for users I do not get any results, although the data structure in Firebase Database is the same for storing the location of cards and users. Please tell me how can I solve this problem?

My structure data

```
"cardLocation" : {
   "-KjLxK0q39JnT2MZEalB" : {
     ".priority" : "v17wefy8z",
     "g" : "v17wefy8z",
     "l" : [ *****, ****** ]
   },
   "-KjM7_5sPkoruwoTvRzR" : {
     ".priority" : "9q5c2ypf3",
     "g" : "9q5c2ypf3",
     "l" : [ ******, -****** ]
   },
   "-KjNDq8nQ2Ffjr9M_1a9" : {
     ".priority" : "9q59x2vc6",
     "g" : "9q59x2vc6",
     "l" : [ *******, -***** ]
   }
 },

"userLocations" : {
   "1Cix149ThIOG1ULPVjyy0LyTxbe2" : {
     ".priority" : "87zc0d2j5",
     "g" : "87zc0d2j5",
     "l" : [ ******, -**** ]
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not correctly use geofire by adding additional property to its model. Now I add only CLLocation to it and it works for me.

```
   let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child(MainGateways.cardLocation.rawValue)
                guard let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef) else { return }
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                geoFire.setLocation(cardLocation, forKey: cardModelRef.key) { (error) in
                    commonError = error
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
```